# Elementwise max in CartesianIndex in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

When I need to get element-wise max of two vectors `a` and `b`, all we need is

```
a = [2,4,5,4]
b = [5,2,8,1]
max.(a,b)
# [5,4,8,4]
```

What if `a` and `b` is CartesianIndex?
The following simple code does not work.

```
a = CartesianIndex(2,4,5,4)
b = CartesianIndex(5,2,8,1)
max.(a,b)
```

In this example, I need `CartesianIndex(5,4,8,4)`.

Then, I wrote the following code.

```
CartesianIndex(max.(a.I,b.I)...)
```

It works, but I am not sure if it is the correct way.
If you have a better idea, I would like to know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max` on `CartesianIndex` values already works that way.

```
julia> a = CartesianIndex(2,4,5,4)
CartesianIndex(2, 4, 5, 4)

julia> b = CartesianIndex(5,2,8,1)
CartesianIndex(5, 2, 8, 1)

julia> max(a, b)
CartesianIndex(5, 4, 8, 4)
```